# Swift Combine - Emit the latest value once per second

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a `PassthroughSubject` which is connected to a `ScrollView` and it emits while it scrolls. I want the subject to emit the current scroll value, but only once per second. I tried `throttle` and `debounce`, but they don't seem to be doing what I need.

Like this, I can see every time it emits while I'm scrolling, so my base setup of scroll detection is working well.

```
scrollSubject
    .sink { value in
        print(value)
    }
    .store(in: &subscription)
```

But when I try to use either of these:

`.throttle(for: 1, scheduler: RunLoop.main, latest: false)` (tried `latest: true` also)`

`.debounce(for: 1, scheduler: RunLoop.main)`

What happens is they are not emitting while I'm scrolling, only after I've stopped it emits the latest value. How is it possible to achieve the desire behaviour?

Comment: What you’re describing is polling. I would do it by making a timer publisher that emits every second and combining that with your scroll subject. I don’t remember the correct way to combine them (`combineLatest` IIRC, but I can check later). You can them map over the result, discarding the time stamps of the timer and just reading out the scroll values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like the `sample` operator available in other reactive programming libraries. It can be implemented in this way like @Alexander is describing:

```swift
extension Publisher {
  func sample(
    every interval: TimeInterval,
    on runLoop: RunLoop,
    in mode: RunLoop.Mode
  ) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: interval, on: runLoop, in: mode)
      .autoconnect()
      .mapError { $0 as! Failure }

    return combineLatest(timer)
      .map(\.0)
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```